# The meaning of the \< and \> regex symbols in GNU grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression, gnu

The following regex example is from pg 22 of "Mastering Regular Expressions".

```
'\<([a-z]+) +\1\>'
```

I'm a novice in regular expressions, but my impression, though the book does not make this clear, is that the `\<` and the `\>` are not standard regex symbols. From searching, it seems these are GNU extensions to the `grep` regular expression syntax. Possibly it's not specific to `grep` - I'm not sure.

In any case, **it's not clear what these symbols mean**. The rest of this question quotes different definitions, or attempts at definitions. Some of which are clearly wrong, incomprehensible, or at least incomplete. If anyone can give me a precis definition I'd appreciate it. I'd say the last one quoted, in https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-9, is the most likely to be correct. But official documentation it is not.

The book says

> You can use the (perhaps odd looking) metasequences `\<` and `\>` [...]. You can think of them as word-based versions of `^` and `$` that match the position at the start and end of a word, respectively.

and then later

> The “start of a word” is simply the position where a sequence of alphanumeric characters begins; “end of word” is where such a sequence ends. Figure 1-2 on the next page shows a sample line with these positions marked.

Figure 1-2 is quite helpful.

It's also "documented" in [The GNU findutils manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html)
which says:

```
‘\<’ matches the beginning of a word
‘\>’ matches the end of a word
```

Also in [The GNU grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) it says:

```
'\<'
    Match the empty string at the beginning of word.
'\>'
    Match the empty string at the end of word.
```

I don't know what either of these descriptions means. So, neither of these two extracts from GNU manuals is helpful.

At the time of originally writing this question, I had not read the "Mastering Regular Expressions" section carefully enough, had not seen Figure 1-2, and thought that these symbols meant that there was a whitespace character either preceding or succeeding the "word". I now realise this is wrong. However, even this book description is
incorrect/incomplete.

Consider these two examples:

```
grep --color -E -i '\<([a-z]+) +\1\>' <<< 'wibble someword someword-something else wibble'
```

"someword someword" is matched here.

```
grep --color -E -i '\<([a-z]+) +\1\>' <<< 'wibble someword someword_something else wibble'
```

Here nothing is matched.

The book doesn't explain this, since it says the "end of word" is where an alphanumeric sequence ends. Neither do the extracts from the GNU manuals.

A possible explanation is provided in https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-9 (found in a random search) which says:

> Searching for a word isn't quite as simple as it at first
> appears. The string "the" will match the word "other". You can put
> spaces before and after the letters and use this regular expression:
> " the ". However, this does not match words at the beginning or end
> of the line. And it does not match the case where there is a
> punctuation mark after the word.

> The character before the "t" must be either a new line character, or
> anything except a letter, number, or underscore. The character after
> the "e" must also be a character other than a number, letter, or
> underscore or it could be the end of line character.

I don't know whether the author got this from, but assuming it's true, it would explain the behavior I'm seeing. But it still seems rather arbitrary. `-` isn't a punctuation mark. Why can't it be included as part of a word? Or, to put it differently, why does the hyphen match
the end of a word, and the underscore doesn't? In fact, the hyphen is much more common in natural languages than the underscore is. Though perhaps the underscore is used in programming languages.

And if this is correct, then the GNU documentation really should document it properly. If I have this straight, would a bug report be in order?

Ideally this feature would be customizable. But perhaps that's asking too much.

This extract from the GNU `grep` code, suggests that the description from [www.grymoire.com](http://www.grymoire.com) may be correct. The relevant code is in function `init_word_char` in 'lib/regcomp.c', and looks like

```
general_case:
  for (; i < BITSET_WORDS; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < BITSET_WORD_BITS; ++j, ++ch)
      if (isalnum (ch) || ch == '_')
        dfa->word_char[i] |= (bitset_word_t) 1 << j;
```

The important line here is, of course line 983 of the file:

```
if (isalnum (ch) || ch == '_')
```

I.e. the character is either alphanumeric or an underscore.

I don't understand what most of this code means, of course.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' "In any case, as this question describes, it's not clear what these symbols mean." Third paragraph.

Comment: As far as I know, the \< and \> regex components came from vi (source code [here](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=4BSD/usr/src/cmd/ex/ex_re.c)) and the definition hasn't really been changed since, except to internationalize the definition of an alphabetic.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Can you elaborate on what that definition is?

Comment: In vi, the definition of a word in a regex is a string of chars where each char c satisfies isalpha(c) || c== '_' || isdigit(c), preceded and succeeded by the inverse of that (or beginning or end of line).

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Is that in line with the grymoire definition? It seems to be, though grymoire singles out newlines for special mention. Still not sure what means the underscore so special.

Comment: vi split a file into individual lines, using newline as a delimiter. Its regex matches didn't cross line boundaries. The grymoire definition seems to amount to the same thing. I'd guess that _ was considered part of a word because a major use of vi was to edit C code, where a variable name consists of alphanumerics and _.

Comment: The definition of word as far as gnu grep is concerned is given in the manual on the same page you linked, under `\w`, where it is described as equivalent to `[_[:alnum:]]`. I don't know why the underscore is included but the convention of classifying it as a word character seems consistent pretty much everywhere regex are used.

Comment: Correction to my first comment: compiling the original vi with a current C compiler will take internationalization into account because it uses the is*() macros. So the definition of a word in a regex hasn't really changed in 40 years.

Comment: @fra-san Thanks for pointing that out. I've tried to fix the errors I could see. Do you see any other issues? Unfortunately cut and paste is fraught with hidden dangers for anything more complex than the alphabet.

Comment: The term _alphanumeric_ is the letters A to Z, including mixed case, accented characters and alternative equivalent alphabets such as Greek and Cyrillic where the locale permits, the digits 0 to 9 or their locale equivalents, and underscore. I'm not sure where that's defined though so I'm hesitant to write this as a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming a formal and precise definition of "word" in relation to regular expressions, while its meaning is actually implementation-dependent.

Indeed, in the paragraph "Regular Expression Nomenclature", "Flavor", the book you are quoting states that

> Even if two programs both support ⌈\<···\>⌋, they might disagree on exactly what they do and don’t consider to be a word".

<sub>As an example of how variable the concept is, the [Regular Expression page on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) defines the `[:word:]` non-standard character class as including the underscore, but the footnote associated with the `[:word:]` symbol links to the [Emacs Lisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html), where it is said that character class matches "any character that has word syntax", further linking to a [Table of Syntax Classes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Class-Table.html#Syntax-Class-Table) that *doesn't* list the underscore among the "word constituents" (listing it among the "symbol constituents" instead—defined as "extra characters used in variable and command names along with word constituents").</sub>

In this light, the apparently inaccurate statement

> The “start of a word” is simply the position where a sequence of alphanumeric characters begins"

is likely to be taken as a simplification rather than a definition.

The expressions "matching the beginning of a word" and "matching the position at the start of a word" don't sound extremely formal either. The version involving the empty string, though less immediately clear, is more precise because the empty string is a [formally defined concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition)<sup>1</sup>.

Practically,

> ‘\<’
>     Match the empty string at the beginning of word.

says that `\<` matches against a string only if that string includes a word-constituent character (according to the GNU grep definition, one in the `[:alnum:]` character class or a `_`) that is not immediately preceded by a word-constituent character.

The `\<([a-z]+) +\1\>` pattern in your example can then be read as "a sequence of one or more lowercase alphabetic characters (which collates between "a" and "z" in your locale), the first of whom is not immediately preceded by a word-constituent character, followed by one or more spaces, followed by the whole previous sequence of lowercase alphabetic characters, the last of whom is not followed by a word-constituent character.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In the context of regular expressions, the string of length zero. It can be matched, and indeed *every* line contains it, including the empty line. Being the [identity element of the concatenation operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_string), it can be matched before or after any literal character. It is, for instance, what `X*` matches in `grep 'oX*o' <<<foo`, or what the empty pattern `''` matches in `grep '' <<<''` or what is matched in `echo "" | grep '^$'`; and, also, what `\<` matches in `grep '\<' <<<'a'`.</sub>

Comment: In the context of Emacs, the definition of "any character that has word syntax" can be configured at runtime; the idea is that the "major mode" for each open file ("buffer") will set it up so that `\<` and `\>` do the intuitive thing for whatever natural or programming language text that file contains.

Answer (score 1):

That part [from the GNU grep manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) says:

> `\<` Match the empty string at the beginning of word.
>
> `\>` Match the empty string at the end of word.

They match at the start and end of a "word", so `\<bar` matches the string `foo bar`, or just `bar`, but not `foobar`. The matches are described as matching an empty string, since when matching  `\<bar` against `foo bar`, the match is just `bar`, not e.g. `<space>bar`, the `\<` doesn't add any characters to the matched string (which is relevant for e.g. `grep -o`).

They're not standard.

> `\w` Match word constituent, it is a synonym for `[_[:alnum:]]`.

This is what the manual says next. Note the small print. Word characters include alphanumerics (whatever that means in the current locale), *and the underscore*. So `someword_something` doesn't match `someword\>` which is effectively what your second `grep` tries to look for.

And yes, that's because in many programming languages alphanumerics and underscores are allowed in identifier names. The hyphen isn't, it's the minus operator.

Though of course in C and Javascript, `$` is also valid in identifier names, and identifier names can't start with digits, but you can't have everything.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Maybe mention that your quotes are from the GNU grep manual, assuming that is where they are from, and provide a link.

Comment: According to Tom Christiansen this inherits from Vi, so that's probably worth mentioning, assuming you know it to be true. Also, I'm not at all familiar with regexes, but am I supposed to know what the expression `‘[_[:alnum:]]’` means?

Comment: @FaheemMitha You probably know that `[ ... ]` is a "character list", so this matches any single character contained in the square brackets (think of it as a convenient "OR" of single characters, only with the possibility to easily define ranges, as in `[a-z]`. The `[:alnum:]` _within_ that character list is a "character class" - a POSIX extension to regular expressions and again a shorthand method for defining "umbrella" character lists. `[:alnum:]` contains all "alphanumeric" characters, i.e. alphabetic characters+numbers. So, `[_[:alnum:]]` matches alphanumeric chars plus the underscore.